# How to achieve the flex-grow + max-width behavior in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to achieve the "flex-grow + max-width" behavior in flutter?

Similar to how you see here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZOgneiKh7J

Thank you!

Comment: I dont understand, probably this is not what you want but https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Comment: The general idea is, for example:

[ fixed 50px w  ] --- [ expands if needed ] --- [ w 50px but can shrink ]